# Oracle ManagedDataAccess 12.x and 4.x - what is the relationship?

Tags: oracle, odp.net

The version numbers of the nuget packes are 12.x

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

However in my may machine.config the version numbers are 4.x

```
 <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
```

What is the relationship between the 12.x and 4.x version numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version `4.121.2.0` means following

- 4 is the version number of .NET Framework. Your application must be compiled to NET Framework version 4.0 or greater, otherwise you cannot use it. The unmanaged `Oracle.DataAccess` exist also for .NET Framework 1.x and 2.x
- `121.2.0` is the Oracle release, it corresponds to Oracle version `12.1.0.2.0`.